# Navigation Drawer : Fragments Overlap

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am creating a simple Navigation Drawer. When I switch between different tabs the content of fragment overlaps the content of main activity

Here's the code of main activity

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        CamFragment camFragment = new CamFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, camFragment).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

My CamFragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cam, container, false);
}
```

ScreenShot of the app

[image]

Comment: It depends on your "content_main" size, in which part you want to show your fragment.

Comment: I want the Cam Fragment to replace the Content of Main Activity as in Gmail App

Comment: Post your `activity_main.xml`